# Why might my code be using my OS's installed Python when I'm running in a virtual environment?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, virtualenv

I'm following [a book](https://www.obeythetestinggoat.com) which introduces Django and at the same time teaches TDD for Python.

The stage I'm at is attempting to use POP to retrieve an email (sent to a yahoo.com address) in order to examine its contents.

I am running everything in a virtual environment on my local machine (which is running tests against a remote server, in my case a VPS hosted by Hostinger). We've just been told to do this, on the local machine (in fact `source` this from a local .env file):

```
YAHOO_PASSWORD=myYahooPassword
```

The failure which this gives is like this:

```
(test_venv369) mike@M17A ~/IdeaProjects/TestingGoat $ STAGING_SERVER=mikerodentstaging.xyz python manage.py test functional_tests.test_login
...
ERROR: test_can_get_email_link_to_log_in (functional_tests.test_login.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mike/IdeaProjects/TestingGoat/functional_tests/test_login.py", line 72, in test_can_get_email_link_to_log_in
body = self.wait_for_email( test_email, SUBJECT )
File "/home/mike/IdeaProjects/TestingGoat/functional_tests/test_login.py", line 28, in wait_for_email
inbox.pass_(os.environ['YAHOO_PASSWORD'])
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'YAHOO_PASSWORD'
```

... and my first puzzled response was to *export* the variable, instead of leaving it as a non-exported variable. This gave another error: the FT hung (!), for about 60 s, before ending thus:

```
ERROR: test_can_get_email_link_to_log_in (functional_tests.test_login.LoginTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/mike/IdeaProjects/TestingGoat/functional_tests/test_login.py", line 72, in test_can_get_email_link_to_log_in
body = self.wait_for_email( test_email, SUBJECT )
File "/home/mike/IdeaProjects/TestingGoat/functional_tests/test_login.py", line 28, in wait_for_email
inbox.pass_(os.environ['YAHOO_PASSWORD'])
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/poplib.py", line 213, in pass_
return self._shortcmd('PASS %s' % pswd)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/poplib.py", line 176, in _shortcmd
return self._getresp()
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/poplib.py", line 152, in _getresp
raise error_proto(resp)
poplib.error_proto: b'-ERR [SYS/TEMP] Server error - Please try again later.'
```

... what I have noticed as strange about both these traces is that they are using my local machine's **installed Python** setup, despite the fact that I am running from a virtual environment.

Why would this happen? Is this maybe because I have failed to install one or more modules in my virtual environment, maybe using `pip`? It is particularly strange in the case of the `os` module, which I would assume to be present in my virtual environment setup as standard. Having said that, I can't actually find an os.py file like this:

```
mike@M17A ~/python_venvs/test_venv369 $  find . -regex '.*/os.py'
```

Incidentally, the testing code itself is rather long, which is why I haven't quoted it so far... this is an extract of the code involved (the `os.environ[ ... ]` line is about halfway through):

```
from django.core import mail
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import poplib
import re
import time
from .base import FunctionalTest

SUBJECT = 'Your login link for Superlists'

class LoginTest(FunctionalTest):
    def wait_for_email(self, test_email, subject):
        if not self.staging_server:
            email = mail.outbox[0]
            self.assertIn(test_email, email.to)
            self.assertEqual(email.subject, subject)
            return email.body
        email_id = None
        start = time.time()
        inbox = poplib.POP3_SSL('pop.mail.yahoo.com')
        try:
            inbox.user(test_email)
            inbox.pass_(os.environ['YAHOO_PASSWORD'])
            while time.time() - start < 60:
                # get 10 newest messages
                count, _ = inbox.stat()
                for i in reversed(range(max(1, count - 10), count + 1)):
                    print('getting msg', i)
                    _, lines, __ = inbox.retr(i)
                    lines = [l.decode('utf8') for l in lines]
                    # print(lines)
                    if f'Subject: {subject}' in lines:
                        email_id = i
                        body = '\n'.join(lines)
                        return body
                time.sleep(5)
        finally:
            if email_id:
                inbox.dele(email_id)
            inbox.quit()
```

Comment: In your virtualenv, can you check which python it's actually using? (`which python`)
This should point to the python installed in your virtualenv. If it points somewhere else you have something strange in your shell setup.

Comment: Thanks, this gives "/home/mike/python_venvs/test_venv369/bin/python"

Comment: And you are sure that the environment variable YAHOO_PASSWORD is set in your shell? Do you get the expected result with `echo "$YAHOO_PASSWORD"`?

Comment: Yes: that prints out the password as per expectations.

Comment: Is the variable exported? Otherwise it wont be inherited by subshells or other processes.
`python -c 'import os; print(os.environ["YAHOO_PASSWORD"])'`

Comment: Did you read the question thoroughly? As I said in my question, my response to the first failure was to change so that it *was* exported. But it is clearly the book author's intention that it should NOT be exported... and that the test should nevertheless pass.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213399/discussion-between-asheidan-and-mike-rodent).

Comment: Hey guys, did you manage to solve this?, i have exactly the same issue, KeyError for YAHOO_PASSWORD, tried recreating the virtual env, dug into yahoo privacy settings ... etc etc cheers